# HTML Creative template served with extra html/body tags

Tags: google-dfp

I'm building a responsive HTML creative template to serve a full screen ad. The ad is displayed on a mobile device, running iOS 6-7, using version 6.8.0 of the DFP SDK. I noticed that when serving an ad with my template, **DFP wraps my HTML with extra html/body tags** (see comments below):

```html
<!-- the code below is from DFP --> 
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0"/>
</head><body leftMargin="0" topMargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- my code starts here --> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
...
<!-- my code ends here -->  
<!-- the code below is from DFP --> 
</body></html>
```

The issue I'm having is that `height=device-height` from the injected HTML code makes my ad **scrollable**. My ads are displayed in **landscape** and for unknown reason `device-height` and `device-width` default to a same value - **the device width**.  The HTML above is not valid because nested `html`/`body` tags and I can't control the viewport definition to remove the erronous `height=device-height`.

Questions:

1. Is there a way to suppress DFP generated wrapping HTML (`<html>...</html>`) and rely on my code to supply it (so I can supply my own `viewport`)
2. Any clues why landscape view of the ad defaults both width and height to the device width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Javascript to update the header:

```js
<script type="application/javascript">
   var meta = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0];
   meta.setAttribute("content", 'width=device-width,user-scalable=0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0');
</script>
```

Comment: On which event did you call this script.

Comment: @all-ok in the body of the HTML page i.e. no event is involved